# Drupal adding rows in comment storage - Where to edit 'INSERT' query?

Tags: php, drupal

I edited the 'comment' table in my Drupal MySQL database to add two rows. This is because I have a page that takes in a URL parameter, so while there is one page, I need to distinguish between the values of that parameter for comments. I'm having trouble editing my `comment.module` to edit the MySQL query. I can't find any kind of `'INSERT into...'` query anywhere, not just in that file. I've looked through everything in the comment module folder.

What appears to be what affects the database insertion is the `comment_publish_action()` function in `comment.module` but I'm still running into some problems regarding the added columns, as they don't have default values.

Here's that function, 'typenode' and 'idofnode' are the added columns with test values:

```
function comment_publish_action($comment, $context = array()) {
  if (isset($comment->subject)) {
    $subject = $comment->subject;
    $comment->status = COMMENT_PUBLISHED;
  }
  else {
    $cid = $context['cid'];
    $subject = db_query('SELECT subject FROM {comment} WHERE cid = :cid', array(':cid' => $cid))->fetchField();
    db_update('comment')
      ->fields(array(
        'status' => COMMENT_PUBLISHED,
        'typenode' => 'player',
        'idofnode' => 1239
      ))
      ->condition('cid', $cid)
      ->execute();
  }
  watchdog('action', 'Published comment %subject.', array('%subject' => $subject));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit comment.module is not good idea. During next core updates all changes will be lost. Better to create a custom module and implement some hooks there.

There is function `comment_save($comment)` which perform steps to insert / update new comment. In this function you can find a line `drupal_write_record('comment', $comment);` which do insert or update of db table 'comment' (dependence on logic). But before this line there is hook `module_invoke_all('comment_presave', $comment);` which allows you to modify $comment object before it will be store in database. This is good way to go - implement this hook in custom module and do modifications there.

```
function custom_module_comment_presave($comment) {
  //add rows info here
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling this is the correct answer, but I haven't been able to check. My comment settings in page editing have disappeared. Similarly, the comments do not appear where they used to. Usually this is because I have comments turned off for that page, but I can't check that because those settings no longer appear... Here's my [Drupal forums question](http://drupal.org/node/1959212), I really have no clue. Any ideas?